# How do I get the NT logged in user using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, servicestack

How do you get the NT login name using JavaScript?

This is how you can do it in webforms:

```
Session("NTLogin") = Page.User.Identity.Name
```

but we want to only run JavaScript on the client side and ServiceStack to connect.

Comment: I'm sure I'm not using the correct terminology to articulate my searches correctly.  I'll follow your suggestion.  Thanks.